# Where do I find the Google Play Services attribution text?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

[Google Maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro#attribution_requirements) says that one has to include the Google Play Services attribution text as part of a "Legal Notices". The attribution text is available by making a call to `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo`. But GooglePlayServicesUtil is not available until Android 2.2. My app is designed for 2.0, so what is this text and where do I get it?

Comment: "GooglePlayServicesUtil is not available until Android 2.3.3" -- where do you see this?

Comment: I'm not sure now. I tried to upgrade to Google Maps 2.0 and I read anywhere that Google Services is not supported below 2.3.3.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html "You can develop on any compatible Android device that runs Android 2.2 or higher and includes the Google Play Store". `GooglePlayServicesUtil` is provided by the Play Services SDK and is not itself version-dependent, AFAICT.

Comment: My app is designed for 2.0, there is no Play Services SDK, isn't it? At least I don't have Google Play on my real device but "Android Market".

Comment: Maps V2 does not support Android 2.0, because it needs OpenGL ES 2.0, and that was not available for Android 2.0. Bear in mind that there are approximately zero devices in use today that run Android 2.0 -- they were all upgraded to something newer (e.g., Android 2.1). To run Maps V2, the device must have OpenGL ES 2.0 and have the Play Services Framework installed. The latter is only available for devices with the Play Store, not the Android Market.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That means, that it's not available on my device, which is Android 2.1. And, as I said, that' why my app is designed for at least 2.0. Otherwise I couldn't run it myself :)

Comment: In which case, your app cannot use Maps V2. You can use Maps V1, though you only have a few days remaining to get your API keys.

Comment: Yes, I use Maps 1.0. Nevertheless I have to display some license info, but there is no built in possibility to do this. So I have to somehow display the text itself in some kind of dialog.

Comment: I use Google Play Services (for AdMob and Analytics), but not Maps. It's not clear whether I need to add the attribution text in my legal notices or not. Is there any Google documentation that clears this doubt ?

Comment: @Sebastien First of all, when use use third party frameworks, code or whatever, you almost always have to add them to the legal notice (depending on the licence, like GPL). If you use AdMob and Analytics, adding it into the legal notice is not just enough. Your users have to accept this EU cookie crap. There is also a solution for this: `https://github.com/Carlosph/CookiesConsent`. I didn't tested it, because I wrote an own solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is what a

```
Log.d("DEBUG", GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(this));
```

reveals (Feb 2013 - this may have changed meanwhile! See the first comment):

> This product includes software from the The Android Open Source
>   Project  Copyright (c) 2005-2008, The Android Open Source Project 
>   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");  you
>   may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  Unless
>   required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
>   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied.  See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and  limitations under the License.
>                                  Apache License
>                            Version 2.0, January 2004
>                         http://www.apache.org/licenses/

And then the [Apache License Version 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) follows.

**Edit Jan 3 2016**: `GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(Context)` is now **deprecated**.

Use `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(Context);` instead.

**Edit Oct 31 '17**
As donfuxx said its no longer need to be shown in app. [Google doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil#getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(android.content.Context))

Comment: GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo() has been removed in Play Services 11.2.0

Comment: Since `GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getOpenSourceSoftwareLic‌​enseInfo()` is removed now: What to use instead?!?

Comment: ok, looks like it is no longer needed at all, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620653/2399024

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I find the attribution information?
>
> You can find the attribution in the line(s) shown on the bottom of the Content in the
>       products along with copyright notices, such as “Map data ©2012 Google, Sanborn”. Note 
>       that the exact text of the attribution changes based on geography and content type. The
>       attribution text must be legible to the average viewer or reader

Taken from: http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html

[Here](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html) is a page with more general info, along with a Permissions Tool you can use if your use-case is more complex.

[This Image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-V1hIqOXDfi4/UNxfrxJNmyI/AAAAAAAAGrM/j59JMYUvNMk/s400/screen_MapsAPIv2_Legal+Notices.png) depicts exactly the text you're looking for.