# GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftware method not available

Tags: android, google-maps, licensing

I am learning GoogleMaps through Lynda.com.In Displaying GooglePlay Services License they used a method called GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftware.I a m not able to find it.Can somebody please point out what the method has changed too? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you mean `getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo()`. If so, they deprecated it, because it is no longer needed. They show their own software licenses in their own apps; you no longer need to show the license information yourself. Quoting what is in [the JavaDocs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(android.content.Context)) at the moment:

> This license information is displayed in Settings > Google > Open Source on any device running Google Play services. Applications do not need to display this license text, and this method will be removed in a future version of Google Play services.

Comment: So i don't need to Show any Licensing Info in my app if i use Google Maps,right?

Comment: @hagrya: You do not have to show any Maps licensing info in your app.